# user_id with value null OctoverCMS

Tags: php, mysql, octobercms, octobercms-backend, octobercms-plugins

I have extended the Rainlabs User plugin, to create a new table to list items created by each user, but the value stored after the save for the **user_id** is NULL.

Here my code :

Model Item.php

```
public $belongsTo = [
    'user' => ['RainLab\User\Models\User', 'key' => 'user_id'],
];
```

And this is what I have in my plugin.php file:

```
public function boot() { 
    User::extend(function($model){ 
        $model->hasOne['item'] = ['Author\Marka\Models\Item'];
    });
}
```

Thank your for the help...

Comment: Is this is a `one-to-one` relationship?

Comment: yes it's a one-to-one relationship...

Comment: I think items created by a user requires a `one-to-many` relation

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i solved the problem by attribute the user_id value on the controller.